# Как получить координаты смещения точки при редактировании полигона yandex map?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Использую редактирование полигона и отслеживаю событие `vertexdrag`. Мне нужно получить координаты смещения точки во время перетаскивания. Событие возвращает `globalPixels`, как это значение конвертировать в обычные координаты карты?

Пробовал использовать метод:

```
myMap.converter.globalToPage(globalPixels, myMap.getZoom())
```

Но получаю неверные значения.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел способ, вдруг кому-то пригодится:

```js
const projection = myMap.options.get('projection')
const coordinates = projection.fromGlobalPixels(globalPixels, myMap.getZoom())
console.log(coordinates) // Bingo!
```